# Excel VBA file increasing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a shared excel file (xlsm) where about 10 users enter into the cells a2 - x2 and then click a button(macro) which copies the data to the last row down.
The macro works but the file size keeps increasing by a lot and I don't know why. Sorry but my vba is very beginner so I have looked up some code online.

```
Sub Submit()
Application.CommandBars("Reviewing").Controls("&Update File").Execute
'this should save the file and then copy the data and paste to last row
ActiveWorkbook.Save
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("a5"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If
    .Cells(2, 25) = Environ("USERNAME")
    .Range("A2:Y" & LastRow).Copy
End With

'sheet to paste too
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If
    .Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
     .Range("B2:F2").ClearContents
     .Range("H2:Q2").ClearContents
     .Range("S2:Y2").ClearContents
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course the file size keeps growing if you add data. But "*keeps increasing by a lot*" is a very vague definition, can you tell a number? How big is your file? How much does it increase per add? How much data rows does it contain? Which Excel format are you using (xls, xlsm, xlsb)? Also a note: If you use `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` then your `Range(` needs to start with a `.` to make use of the `With` statement like `.Range(` same for `Cells(2, 25)`. If you don't do this then VBA assumes the active sheet which might be wrong.

Comment: I have now updated my code. The file size was 48kb with just over 100 rows added before any macro was run and when the macro is run it is increasing in size by about 5kb every time it is already over 5mb.

Comment: I'd check that everything is being recorded properly - I tried this as a test when asked to have a shared workbook with multiple people adding data to the next available row.  With just 2 people using it they were overwriting each others data as each person has a copy of the shared workbook with their own last rows - when saved it combines the workbooks and messes up who's update to put on which row.  Have a read of this link for a better explanation:  https://excel.tips.net/T002998_Losing_Data_in_a_Shared_Workbook.html

Comment: I have now added more data to this file and based on 7000 rows of data columns A-Y the file now increases by 140kb each time the macro is run (adds a row)

Comment: Darren, thankyou for your comment but if you look at my macro the user will always enter into the rows a2 -X2 and the click a button Submit which is assigned to a macro. The macro first updates the workbook and saves before copying the new row of data therefore the data will not be overwritten. I have already tested this with a few users and it works fine. its just the file size I can't work out.